# VLOOKUP: Return multiple INDEX values in single VLOOKUP and SUM results

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

I filter a dynamic range of Columns as an INDEX in an VLOOKUP, based on a cell reference. In this case I would get three columns back. Afterwards I pick one of them (INDEX 1 in example).

```
=VLOOKUP($A2, Sheet1!$A$3:$W, index(filter(arrayformula(column(Sheet1!$A$1:$1)),Sheet1!$A$1:$1=E$1),,1),false)
```

Since I have to return INDEX 2 and INDEX 3 as well and SUM them up afterwards, I pretty much repeat this formula per INDEX (3 times in this example)

```
=VLOOKUP($A2, Sheet1!$A$3:$W, index(filter(arrayformula(column(Sheet1!$A$1:$1)),Sheet1!$A$1:$1=E$1),,1),false) + 
=VLOOKUP($A2, Sheet1!$A$3:$W, index(filter(arrayformula(column(Sheet1!$A$1:$1)),Sheet1!$A$1:$1=E$1),,2),false) + 
=VLOOKUP($A2, Sheet1!$A$3:$W, index(filter(arrayformula(column(Sheet1!$A$1:$1)),Sheet1!$A$1:$1=E$1),,3),false)
```

I am wondering if there is a way to get the SUM of INDEX 1-3 but with just one formula. Here a picture to help understanding my setup:

[image: Example Picture]

I am looking for every Column with GroupX as a reference, return Index1 and Index2 and SUM the values afterwards. How can I do that without repeating the formula 3 times and type in the INDEX manually.

Comment: Here you go. The formula in Database!E3 is what I am talking about.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n5SvJBO3qe9uwa5aINFVBXUgXI1WKp9c9KVeO3tM860/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `INDEX` and just use `FILTER` and it will return multiple columns meeting the condition. Also, you can remove `IFERROR` here since only valid columns are returned, thus there should be a value always, no `#REF` values anymore.

#### Formula E2:

```
=divide(
sum(arrayformula(switch(VLOOKUP($A2, Sheet1!$A$3:$J, filter(column(Sheet1!$A$1:$1),Sheet1!$A$1:$1=E$1),false),"done",1,"wip",0.5,"open",0)))
,countif(Sheet1!$A$1:$1,E$1))
```

#### Formula E7:

```
=divide(
sum(arrayformula(switch(VLOOKUP($A7, Sheet2!$A$3:$J, filter(column(Sheet2!$A$1:$1),Sheet2!$A$1:$1=E$1),false),"done",1,"wip",0.5,"open",0)))
,countif(Sheet2!$A$1:$1,E$1))
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- IDs ending in B, I used `Sheet2`, and just copy pasted to rows 7-11
- Pardon for the background colors, it wasn't formatted properly like yours.

Comment: This does solve the above statet problem! Thanks a lot for taking the time. Next step is to avoid having to refer to a sheet manually but getting it dynamically as well. I think this could work with `indirect`. Something like this:

`indirect(TypeReference&"!A3:D")`

But lets see where I end up with :)